# How to set the background image for a textarea on click of a button?

Tags: java, swing, applet

I want to set an image for a textarea as background image, on click of a button. How is this possible?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.GrayFilter;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class BackgroundSample {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Background Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("draft.gif");
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea() {
      Image image = imageIcon.getImage();

      Image grayImage = GrayFilter.createDisabledImage(image);
      {
        setOpaque(false);
      }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(grayImage, 0, 0, this);
    super.paint(g);
  }
};
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
Container content = frame.getContentPane();
content.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(250, 250);
frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

This is what I referred to. How to do about the same thing, but with the actionlistener(on click of button)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into event listeners, in particular action listeners?

Comment: I was able to display background image in the text area while calling the constructor for the textarea, but I'm not sure how to do this with the action listener.

Comment: and for the info, I am dealing with an applet here..

Comment: Remove the HTML tag from your question

Comment: Please check that code formats as you expect.  Two '} }' are missing from the formatted code in that example.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to extend your JTextPane class and create a `setImage(Image image)` method. This method would save the reference of the image and then invoke repaint().

Also, you should be overriding the paintComponent() method, not the paint() method. Ignore any tutorial that says otherwise as it is 10 years out of date.

Comment: i've tried something. but it doesnt seem to work.. Can u please tell me what is the problem. This is my code http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44103654/ColorPalette.java

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class MyTextArea extends JTextArea {
    private Image backgroundImage;

    public MyTextArea() {
        super();
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    public void setBackgroundImage(Image image) {
        this.backgroundImage = image;
        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        if (backgroundImage != null) {
            g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
        }

        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Then in your action listener:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Image image = ImageIO.read(..);
    if (image != null)
        textArea.setBackgroundImage(image);     
}
```

Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BackgroundDemo {
    private static void createAndShowUI() {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("BackgroundDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();

        final MyTextArea textArea = new MyTextArea();
        textArea.setText("Some text");

        JButton loadButton = new JButton("Set background");
        buttonsPanel.add(loadButton);

        loadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.home"));
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        Image image = ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile());
                        if (image != null)
                            textArea.setBackgroundImage(image);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        content.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(content);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class MyTextArea extends JTextArea {
        private Image backgroundImage;

        public MyTextArea() {
            super();
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        public void setBackgroundImage(Image image) {
            this.backgroundImage = image;
            this.repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            if (backgroundImage != null) {
                g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
            }

            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: -1, 1) the class name should not be TextArea since there is an AWT component by that name already which can lead to confusion. 2) You wouldn't create an ImageIcon just to read the image. Instead you would probably use ImageIO. 3) no real need to clutter the forum since this answer was given 2 hours earlier. Spoon feeding code doesn't help and can introduce bad habits as noted by points 1 & 2.